# How to password protect a string of text?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I've seen lots of similar questions but not quite sure which is applicable to this situation. I have a program that sends sensitive information by email. I would like the email to be scrambled such that the recipient must know the password in order to unscramble and read it. How can this be done? I guess I'm looking for some sort of asymmetric key encryption.

Comment: Try using base64 to encode and decode.Also,Please post your code for more clear answer.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal how does that help? Anyone can decode base64 as it doesn't require a password.

Comment: Yep,got it.Even if you use SHA-256 we have online tools to decode it.And, may I know how you are wishing the recipient will get the password?

Comment: @HemaNandagopal it would already be exchanged before hand. Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: I don't think you can password protect an email while sending but you can send the sensitive data as an attachment in email. And the attachment can be password protected.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, the key has been exchanged before hand, so the same key can be used for both encryption and decryption.
In this case, all you need is symmetric encryption.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) common  and recent/secure algorithms are

- AES
- Serpent
- Twofish

Comment: Even if you encrpt the email content, how will email client on user end decrypt it with your key? I don't think it's a good idea to ask user to copy the content from email and then decrypt using another tool.

Comment: Blowfish, DES and TDES are no longer recommended for use by most security professionals.  Might want to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Certificate based encryption , essentially asymmetric using public-private key pairs distributed as certificate.

So when you send an email to a user , you encrypt using the public certificate of the user , the user will be the only entity who can de-crypt the email using his private key .

When the recipient receives the email and replies back , he will again encrypt the email using your public key and that way the reply can be de-crypted only by you.